# How can I get legend for coplot in r?

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, lattice

Using the `iris` dataset, I am going to find a way to get the legend in `coplot` when I define the color of point as `variable` variable, in this example (`Species`). 
in other words, I want to see a **legend** to tell me *which shape and color represent which Species*?

following is the script

```
coplot(Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length|Petal.Width*Petal.Length, data = iris,
number=c(3,3),overlap=.5,col=as.numeric(iris$Species),
pch=as.numeric(iris$Species)+1)
```

this is the produced graph:
[image]

Comment: you can do this with `legend` .. `legend("topright", legend=unique(iris$Species), col=1:3, pch=2:4, xpd=NA)` although prbably want to find a position that's better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
coplot(Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length|Petal.Width*Petal.Length, data = iris,
       number=c(3,3),overlap=.5,col=as.numeric(iris$Species),
       pch=as.numeric(iris$Species)+1)

legend("topright", pch = unique(as.numeric(iris$Species)+1), 
       col = unique(as.numeric(iris$Species)), 
       legend = unique(iris$Species))
```

You just have to adjust legend position to what fits better to your figure size.

Comment: you can use locator(1) to find the coordinates of where you would like to place the upper left corner of the plot.

Comment: @G5W Absolutelly!

Comment: @G5W Can you please explain more how to use locator(1) and what do you mean exactly? I am newbie and learning . Do you also have a reference for me to refer to learn more about legend coordination? tnx.

Comment: To get help on any command type `?command`   so `?legend` and `?locator` would be in order. Locator, let's you click on an existing graph and tells you the x-y coordinates of the place that you clicked.  "topright"  wasn't working well for me with your graph,  so I tried placing the legend using x-y coordinates derived from locator.

Comment: @G5W, another naive question , any idea how I can get rid of the border or the box around the legend to make it more readable and adjustable?

Comment: Slightly obscure, but also in the documentation `?legend`.  You can use bty='n'.

Comment: Use `locator(1)` and click on the plot in the desired position for the legend. R will return x and y position values. Then add the position to the legend as `legend(x = 3, y = 7.5, ...` for example, in place of "topright" .This position refers to the topleft corner of the legend.